# Accessible and dynamic animated information box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have started with the [example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-animated-information-box) and added to the code to make it:

- Dynamic in height
- Accessible with JS turned off

Have I done this correct? Will this work on most browsers?

Working version visable [here](http://dev.web2works.co.uk/animate-information-box/):

Original:

```
$('#example-links a').hover(function(){
    var index = $("#example-links a").index(this);
    $('#example-content').animate({"marginTop" : -index*220 + "px"}); // multiply by height+top/bottom padding/margin/border
});
```

My modified code, it just seems a little long compared to the above:

```
var maxHeight = 0, container_maxHeight = 0;
var example_content = $("#example-content");
var example_div = example_content.children("div");

example_div.each(function() {   
    if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
        container_maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    }
});
example_div.height(maxHeight);

$("#example-content-container").css({
    "overflow":"hidden",
    "height": container_maxHeight+"px"
}); 

$('#example-links a').bind('click mouseover', function(e){
    var index = $("#example-links a").removeClass("active").index(this);
    $(this).addClass("active");
    example_content.stop().animate({"marginTop" : -index*container_maxHeight + "px"});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I bind both the click and mouseover because I want it to work via mouseover but then I also want it to work when browsing on a mobile phone that doesn't have a mouse to activate the hover.

Comment: I would not consider your "JS-free" version as very accessible/user friendly. Clicking the links has no effect, which is very confusing. See @Shef's answer and my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine, the only thing I would add to make it more accessible if JS is off, are the section ids. You can [check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/AYYQ8/).

For each section, you add an id to the wrapping div, and then on your side links you link to that id.

I would clean up your code a little bit more:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var maxHeight = 0, container_maxHeight = 0,
            example_content = $("#example-content"),
            example_div = example_content.children("div");

        example_div.each(function() {   
            var $section = $(this);
            if($section.height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $section.height();
                container_maxHeight = $section.outerHeight(true);
            }
        });
        example_div.height(maxHeight);

        $("#example-content-container").height(container_maxHeight);        

        var $tabs = $('#example-links a');
        $tabs.bind('click mouseover', function(e){
            var index = $tabs.removeClass("active").index(this);
            $(this).addClass("active");
            example_content.stop().animate({"marginTop" : -index*container_maxHeight + "px"});
            e.preventDefault();
        });                            
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function(){   var $ = jQuery;` you can also use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` - besides that, using noConflict without it being necessary is kind of stupid; simply wrap all the code in a `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` and it will always work

Comment: In addition, without JS, you can achieve similar functionality with the CSS3 `:target` pseudo selector: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/AYYQ8/2/embedded/result/ (which is actually pretty cool, if supported by the browser)

Comment: The :target looks really interested if only everyone updated their browsers more often.